# We need to change URL structure of our product page in PRESTASHOP theme

Tags: seo, prestashop-1.6

We are using PRESTASHOP theme. We need to change url structure of our site. Currently site URL structure is: 
http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?id_product=3013&controller=product&id_lang=1

It should change to:

http://www.mydomain.com/categoryname/productname

So will it be possible? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by going to Preferences > SEO & URLS

Then set Friendly URL to Yes in the Set up URLs section

Finally, on the same page, you can customize your urls (products, categories...) in the     Options section